# MS Text Analytics Cognitive Service: how to work with local database?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services

Microsoft provides a service to analyze text data called Text Analytics Cognitive Service.

Is it possible to use this service with local database? i.e. not in Azure

I work with some large databases and as for me it can be interesting to use it for:
Language detection
Key phrase extraction 
Named Entity recognition
Sentiment analysis

Comment: Its a API service you have to call it from your application with relevant parameters, whats the point to use with local database I am not clear, could you please explain a more.

Comment: I have edited the start message

Comment: I am also using for our bot to detect user language. So database is not a roadblock to use text analytical service. Once you can request API  what you wanted to detect you can it doesn't matter where you are pulling the value from either from database or from directly user.

Comment: Yes, but for example: the db is aggregate news from different sources in different languages and different topics. I'd like to recognize a language of news, analyze it etc. Thats why the question.

Comment: Yes definitely you can, just need to pull your data from db which you wanted to analysis through the service API, then pass it to API param in response you would get your language information. showing you example as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Once you pull your data that you would like to detect its language
>   from your local database, you just need to fetch it then just pass in
>   below method. It would analysis your value in response.

**`API Access Keys:`**

```cs
        private static readonly string endpointKey = "YourEndPonitKey";
        private static readonly string endpoint = "https://YourServiceURL.cognitiveservices.azure.com/text/analytics/v2.1/languages";
```

**`Code Snippet:`**

```cs
    public async Task<object> DetectLanguageAsync(string InputFromDbOrUser)
    {
        try
        {
            DetectedLanguageResponseModel ObjDitectedLanguageResponse = new DetectedLanguageResponseModel();
            //Create laguage detection request param
            RequestModel objRequestModel = new RequestModel();
            objRequestModel.id = "1";
            objRequestModel.text = InputFromDbOrUser;

            //Made Document List
            List<RequestModel> Objdocuments = new List<RequestModel>();
            Objdocuments.Add(objRequestModel);
            //Bind Request Model
            LanguageDetection objRequestList = new LanguageDetection();
            objRequestList.documents = Objdocuments;

            // Bind and Serialize Request Object 
            var serializedObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objRequestList);

            // Call Language Detection API   
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage())
            {
                request.Method = HttpMethod.Post;
                request.RequestUri = new Uri(endpoint);
                request.Content = new StringContent(serializedObject, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                request.Headers.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", endpointKey);

                var response = await client.SendAsync(request);

                //Check status code and retrive response

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {

                    ResponseModel objResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseModel>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
                    //Check Response List
                    foreach (var item in objResponse.documents)
                    {

                        //Checkings Empty Response and Return to Caller
                        if (objResponse.documents != null)
                        {
                            ObjDitectedLanguageResponse.Language = objResponse.documents[0].detectedLanguages[0].name;
                            return ObjDitectedLanguageResponse;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return "Sorry, I am not able to find a related topic! Would you like me to Bing Search?";
                        }

                    }


                }
                else
                {
                    var result_string = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    return result_string;
                }
            }
            return ObjDitectedLanguageResponse;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException(ex.Message, ex.InnerException);
        }

    }
```

**`Class Used:`**

```cs
public class DetectedLanguage
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string iso6391Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class DetectedLanguageResponseModel
    {
        public dynamic Language { get; set; }
    }

    public class LanguageDetection
    {
        public List<RequestModel> documents { get; set; }
    }

    public class RequestModel
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string text { get; set; }
    }
    public class ResponseDocument
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public List<DetectedLanguage> detectedLanguages { get; set; }
    }
    public class ResponseModel
    {
        public List<ResponseDocument> documents { get; set; }
        public List<object> errors { get; set; }
    }
```

> **Note:** The current limit is 5,120 characters for each document; if you need to analyze larger documents, you can break them up into
>   smaller chunks for more you could refer [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/text-analytics/overview#data-limits)

Hope that would help. If you need more implementation assistance [please have a look on here](https://westcentralus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/TextAnalytics-v2-1/operations/56f30ceeeda5650db055a3c7)

Comment: Thanx for the useful sample. But one thing: is it free to use the service?

Comment: Though its not a free service at all but there is a free trial you can have a look [pricing](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/cognitive-services/text-analytics/)